# Notification listener service not receiving post events?[api 18]

Tags: android, notifications

Ive looked around and found some examples of using the new notificationlistenerservice class, but im having issues with it not even hearing the notification post event.

the examples that im finding are using a gui and broadcast receivers which arent really needed by my goal.

im trying to fire off toast notifications at least with this, but i get nothing. i have verified that the application is allowed to listen to notifications and has notifications enabled.

Anything im missing?

```
//listen for new notifications?
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sbn.getPackageName().toString(), 1).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "anything? anything? please?", 1).show();

}

//listen for the removal of the notities 
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    //uhh not done yet
}

//prepare
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //ongoing notification test, is this needed for notification listeners?
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    myNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("NotifyWake")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_open)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
    //end ongoing notification

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you must create some threaded or broadcasted method to offload anything from the post/removed events. things like toast do not work since the method fires off a threading error and silently fails(noted in logcats)

so, a simple solution is to extend broadcastreceiver and pass the heavy lifting and gui stuff to that method.